# Virtual Box no inicia

Tags: virtualbox

Tengo un problema con Virtual Box, después de hacer doble clic no inicia y no sé como abordar el problema ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba trabajando sin problema con la versión VirtualBox-5.0.16-105871-Win en Windows 10, cuando de repente dejo de trabajar tal vez después de una actualización de windows, volvi a ejecutar el instalador de virtual Box, la misma versión y le de clic en repara, y nada... no tengo un punto de restauración del equipo antes de la acutalización :/ ...eliminé las actualizaciones instaladas y nada ...

Ahora no se si desinstalar Virtual Box e instalar la misma versión, o instalar la última versión, tengo miedo que se pierdan las máquinas virtuales que tengo configuradas ...

Gracias por el apoyo.

**Edición** para que cumpla con las normas del sitio:

1) se desactivo SmartScreen y nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Se desinstaló actualización de driver de audio y nada:

Comment: Dale clic derecho al acceso directo y revisa sus propiedades, revisa si apunta al ejecutable de virtualbox.

Comment: Hola @Mauricio, si efectivamente apunta a el ejecutable, "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe", incluso dandoloe clic a el tampoco funciona, ni dandolo clic como administrador... :/

Comment: Puede ser que el _SmartScreen_ de su equipo bloquee la apertura de este programa., revisa el administrador de tareas y finaliza los procesos que puedan estar abiertos de tipo _VBoxSVC.exe_. Revisa esta [pregunta](http://superuser.com/q/872335). Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: @Mauricio desactive SmartScreen y nada :/, y tampoco tengo procesos tipo VBoxSCV.exe corriendo, estoy revisando lo del hash pero aún no doy como verificarlo ..

Comment: Nos pasó exactamente lo mismo. ¿Solución? Desinstala esa versión de VirtualBox y descarga la ÚLTIMA VERSIÓN (5.1) https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads . Esa fue la única solución. Las virtuales puedes no eliminarlas y asi al instalar la nueva versión las recuperarás.

Comment: Cabe decir me pasó exactamente lo mismo y lo que pasaba con el Virtual es que se crasheaba, y en los procesos no duraba ni 2 segundos, solo aparecía rapidamente un proceso de Windows de "Reporte de Error" o algo similar, y desaparecía también. Eso sucedió luego de una actualización de Win10, tal como a tí.

Comment: @AgustinM. Muchas gracias, eso era lo que queria saber. hice lo que me recomendaste tal cual y ya tengo otra vez VirtualBox corriendo con todas mis máquinas virtuales intactas, incluso aquellas que tenia en estado cerrado con el estado guardado "Save the state machine". :)

Comment: Perfecto. Puedes colocar sobre mi comentario un voto positivo y colocaré como respuesta ya que es la solución.

Comment: Perfecto @AgustinM, pero no me aparece la opción de votar en el comentario :/

Comment: Ahí voté sobre tu comentario. No hay problema, coloca mi respuesta como la correcta y listo :-)

Comment: Descargan la ultima versión y lo instalan, no es necesario desistalar la otra versión. SOLUCIONADO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**La solución como coloqué en el comentario arriba es re-instalar el Virtual Box con la última actualización.**

***Explicación:***

Me sucedió exactamente lo mismo hace unas semanas: tenía esa versión del VirtualBox (5.0) corriendo en una máquina con Windows 10.

El Windows 10 debió descargar alguna actualización automática y un día la máquina se había reiniciado y al querer abrir el Virtual Box no sucedía nada.

Busqué muchisimo, en inglés y castellano, y lo más raro de mi problema es que no me salía ningun tipo de ventana de error ni reporte. Solo logré rastrear que el proceso del VBox se cerraba y por unos segundos aparecía uno de Windows llamado algo así como "Proceso de Reporte de Errores" y luego desaparecía también.

Opté por re-instalar la misma versión de Virtual Box pero eso no funcionó.

Soluciones que intenté antes de la definitiva (actualizar Virtual Box):

1. Eliminar los Registros de VirtualBox en el Regedit.
2. Limpiar las carpetas dónde se instalaba el Virtual Box.

**Logré solucionarlo re-instalando la nueva, y última, versión de Virtual Box.**

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: En el siguiente orden lo que hice fue: 1. Desinstalar la versión actual, 2. Instalar la última versión. Tal cual como lo digiste en el comentario: "Nos pasó exactamente lo mismo. ¿Solución? Desinstala esa versión de VirtualBox y descarga la ÚLTIMA VERSIÓN"